# "at risk of" What verb is this phrase connected with?

Tags: tense, verbs, future-tense

> I would be happy if you could choose form of transport so that my parcel would not be **put** [?] at the risk of damage .

I am not sure about using verb "put" with the phrase "at the risk of". Maybe there should be "be" only. I would be grateful if you could check also tenses :)

Answer (score 1):

*Put* is one of those "low-level" English words that can mean a lot of different things and be used in a lot of different ways.

Probably the overall idea expressed by *X puts Y {preposition} Z* is that X takes some action to make "Y {preposition} Z" happen.  "{Preposition} Z" here is usually expresses location or physical orientation.

> He put the cup in the cupboard.
>
> She's putting the dishes on the table now.

But there's a couple things (not very many) that aren't locations that work with *put* when used like above, such as:

> *Put at a disadvantage*: I was put at a disadvantage by coming unprepared.
>
> *Put at risk*: This behavior puts you at risk.
>
> *Put on notice, leave (work status)*: You were put on leave 2 weeks ago, you need to contact HR to resolve.

Note that for "put at *the* risk of damage", you shouldn't use *the* unless a specific single or known risk of damage was mentioned previously.  "Put at a risk a damage" or "put at risk of damage" is better.

As far as the tense, it's correct.  Hard to get a plain *put* wrong as it's the same form in present, past, and past participle.